Whats the error?

I'm trying to make a counter but Vivado display an error, and I cannot see what's the problem. As far as I know the design is correct.
Someone can tell if I'm missing something, please.

please do not post screenshots of text ... post the text instead ... links to code are also unacceptable ... please correct your post ... https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Consider providing the Vivado error as well as the VHDL code as text, allowing the error to be reproduced as well as showing up in search.

Swap
q <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(q)) + 1;

with
q <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(q) + 1);

Your mistake is converting q to unsigned value of its binary representation and converting it back to binary again without incrementing it. It is a parenthesis issue, basically.
